# How to push multiple Arguments in Named Routes flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, arguments, navigator

I'm aware that my question had been asking several time but unfortunately I could not found what I'm looking for there.

I wanna send multiple arguments from one screen to another using On generates routes.

this is my Navigator line, I wanna send along side the **selectedAmount** the **selectedIndexes** they both a numbers

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.digitalBusinessGuideInstructions, arguments: selectedAmount)
```

Here is my Routes cases

```
case AppRoutes.digitalBusinessGuideInstructions:
  final int selectedAmount = settings.arguments as int;
  return AppPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => DigitalBusinessGuideInstructions(
      selectedAmount: selectedAmount,
    ),
  );
```

Comment: You can use map or custom model

Comment: Could you please explain more ?

Comment: what is `selectedAmount` dataType in your case

Comment: selectedAmount  is numbers so it's int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments any object, For now I am passing map

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
  "",
  arguments: {
    "item1Key": selectedAmount,
    "item2Key": 3,
  },
);
```

And receive like  `settings.arguments as Map?;` then read the map for items

```dart
  final args = settings.arguments as Map?;

  final selectedAmount = args?["item1Key"];
  final item2Value = args?["item2Key"];
```

Comment: I'm sorry Could you please explain this part 
" And receive like  settings.arguments as Map?; then read the map for items"
  on my code, I saw that solution but I can't do it

Comment: added , you find more about [Map](https://api.dart.dev/be/180360/dart-core/Map-class.html) and [passing arguments](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)